# how to generate sitemap in joomla

Tags: joomla1.5

How to generate site map in joomla. Can any one guide me the plugin required for sitemap.

Answer (score 0):

[XMap](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/structure-a-navigation/site-map/3066) should do the trick.